# How to extract source code from installed app?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I was developing an Android app for more than a month, but my computer crashed and I lost all the code from it. I have a compiled app installed on a test phone and tablet. Is there any way to extract source code from it?
I followed some guide for game modders (they are probably doing something similar), and I  have extracted .apk with an app called `Total Commander`. Now the guide states that I should extract it with the `apktool`. But all files are still in binary (when I opened them I got random chars). Now, is there any tool (for Linux) that can decompile .apk back to source code, or maybe some feature of `apktool` I miss?

**Note:** [I also tried this answer from 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file) but also without success.
**EDIT:**  javadecompileonline also did not decompile binaries correctly,
so this should be `.json` file:

```
<m*/��%kي%jTƴ���69/�t��
č   �Cx���Q�đš?������i�
ć���/��i�JRᙱg�.�s
```

Comment: try this online tool http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you go to Android studio's welcome  page there is a option to extract source code from APKs.

Another way is to install this apk extractor application from play store  then you can extract source code from APKs Link :  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui